# Plotly includes dates that are missing from the data in the x-axis

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

Having financial data, there is no data over weekends/bank holidays/etc. In the example below I used [this data set](https://gist.github.com/drorata/68346db1dddcdb3eb303ffb8018e93a6).

Assume having a dateframe where the index consists of timestamps then naively plotting the data using:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

fig = df["open"].plot()
```

returns:

[image]

which is great... except the straight lines connecting the missing data. Adding:

```py
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type="category"))
```

Is almost perfect:

[image]

**How can I now get the same tickers (Year, Month, day without the hours)?** Once the index is treated as a category then I cannot use date formatter like `%b` and co.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296518/set-plotly-go-line-graph-rangebreaks-to-exclude-non-business-hours-and-weekends) answer your question? If not, I'm happy to post an answer

Comment: Reviewing the data presented, I see that there are weekends, holidays, after-hours trading, etc., so I think the answer depends on how you want to deal with the deficiencies, although certain rules, as noted in the comments, can be used to address them.

Comment: I suspect it is not helping my case. I want to get the lower result without loosing the datetime awareness of the x-axis ticks.